# Estimate the tuning parameter in Ridge logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, ridge-regression, regression-strategies, regularization

I need to know how can we estimate the *tuning* parameter in penalized likelihood?

I write my own code but there is a mistake I could not find it.!!
Could you please help, I do my best to make the code clear..

Given the likelihood that

$l(\beta)= \sum_i y_i log (\pi_i)+(1-y_i)log (1-\pi) -1/2 \lambda \sum_j {\beta_j}^2$

where $\pi_i= logit^{-1} (x\beta$) and $y_i$ belong to (0,1)

I need to chose the lambda using cross validation ; my question is that

- I need to include the Code B inside Code A. then I can run the code.
- is the code correct or no. Is there any way to make it faster.\

**Code A :**  The *Cross Validation* to choose $\lambda$

```
   PE=c()
lambda=c(0.005,0.001,0.1,0.5,0.2)

for(j in 1:length(lambda)){
print(lambda[j])
tem.PE=c()
for(i in 1:2014){
cv.y=y[-i]
cv.x=x[-i,]
tem.lambda=lambda[j]
## I need to put the function /WNRfit/  here to calculate the Coefficients -Betas-
f.hat=fit$fitted
#   print(f.hat)
tem.PE[i]=mean(cv.y-f.hat)
rm(cv.y,cv.x,fit,f.hat,tem.lambda)
}
PE[j]=mean(tem.PE)
rm(tem.PE)
}
```

**Code B :**
The Newton raphson for estimate beta $\hat{\beta}$

```
   WNRfit <- function(y,X,m=rep(1,length(y)),start=0,n.iter=10,tol=1e-4,verbose=TRUE) {
   W=matrix(0,nrow=length(y),ncol=length(y))
   diag(W)<-m
  n.pred <- ncol(X)
  b <-  matrix(NA,ncol=n.iter,nrow=n.pred)
  b[,1] <- start
  for (i in 2:n.iter) {
  if (verbose) cat(i,"\n")
  p <- plogis(X %*% b[,i-1])
  v.2 <- diag(c(p*(1-p)))
  score.2 <- t(X) %*% W %*% (y - p) # score function
  increm <- solve(t(X)%*%W%*%v.2%*%W%*%X) 
  b[,i] <- b[,i-1]+increm%*%score.2
  if (all(abs(b[,i]-b[,i-1]) < tol))

   return(b)
   fitted=exp(X%*%b[,10])/(1+exp(X%*%b[,10]))

   }
  print(b)
  }
```

Comment: Please see SO help on how to write a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular you need to show why you think you've made a mistake. In addition, making code clear entails explaining what it's doing in comments - especially important when not all readers are familiar with the programming language you're using.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to choose a method before writing the code.  To answer your overall question, I prefer to choose $\lambda$ to optimize the "effective AIC" when can be stated as the penalized model likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ minus twice the effective degrees of freedom.  This is discussed in my book *Regression Modeling Strategies* and details, with R code, may be found at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/FHHandouts/iscb98.pdf